# React renders unnecessary components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [this](https://carpben.github.io/Choose-My-Next-Destination/) simple Create-React-App application , I have a simple, static, Header component. For readability the header is held in a separate component. When using : Dveloper Tools - React - and selecting heighlight updates, I'm surprised to see that the Header component renders each time the destination changes. Of course this happens because the state of the parent, the App component, changes.

It was originally build as a functional component; I tried changing it to a React.pureComponent and React.Component with a 'shouldComponentUpdate' function that returns false but it did not help - the component still gets updated/rendered.

I guess this gets to the 'Virtual Dom' and does not render to the actual dom, but in more complicated apps it is still costly. Any suggestions?
[Code](https://github.com/carpben/Choose-My-Next-Destination)

### Update

I've forked the original repository to demonstrate the issue. In [this](https://choose-my-next-destination-2.firebaseapp.com/) example the Header component is build with React.Component and shouldComponentUpdate returns false. Yet the header renders each time the destination changes.
[Code](https://github.com/carpben/choose-your-next-destination-should)

Comment: PureComponent doesn't implement shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: Your code doesn’t demonstrate what you describe above. Please provide a minimal example to reproduce the behavior you observe.

Comment: Make your Header component extend React.Component and define shouldUpdateComponent() -> false.

Comment: @JoelCornett Please check the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning false from the `ShouldComponentUpdate` method React does not run the render method. I confirmed it by adding a `console.log` command.

However Chrome’s React extension - heighlight updates - still heiglights the Header. The reason for it might be that Header is a sub-component of the App Component, and since the render method of App runs, the Header is heighlighted.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to convert your `App` component to a simple wrapper component around `ControlPanel` and `presentation`. Create a new `App` component which includes the `Header` and `Footer`, along with the wrapper component. Please ensure that the `App` does not have any state of it's own, to avoid re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not worry about it, just keep your render functions as cheap as possible and let React do its work.

If you take care to just pass inn the needed props to any component, keep the components as simple as possible and in a sane structure, and make any expensive calculations outside the simple components (to keep them between state changes), that's all the optimizing I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Header is not a component that can implement shouldComponentUpdate.

Implement Header like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import globeLogo from './globe.svg'

export default class Header extends React.Component{

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //compare props and state if need to and decide whether to render or not
  //Other wise just return false;
}
render(){
 return (
        <div className="App-header">
            <img src={globeLogo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1>Choose My Next Destination</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Hope that will resolve your query :)

Comment: I added two parameters to the shouldComponentUpdate - with the names nextProps and nextState. Then I simply return false. However, the Header components continues to render every single time the destination changes. https://github.com/carpben/choose-your-next-destination-should/blob/master/src/_components/Header.js

Comment: If you are using a client side routing technique like react-router or so, you should put the Header outside your <Router> tag.

Comment: I'm not using react-router.